# How do I restart my cron service on my Ubuntu AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a cron job I've just set up and I'm trying to run `/etc/init.d/cron restart` while SSH'd into my instance. It's asking for my instance password which I've never set. Is there a default instance password I can use so my cron works?

Thanks

Comment: try `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`

Comment: Why would you want to restart cron? You don’t need to after modifying the crontab.

Comment: My understanding is that I have to restart it after creating my crontab file. Am I incorrect?

Comment: You dont have to restart the service after changing cron jobs.